# How to define permission to everyone in a WebDAV on MAC OS X Catalina

Tags: macos, iis, webdav

I mounted a WEBDAV Share on my Mac Catalina viy Finder -> GOTO SEVER and use https:///webdav.
It works fine and the Mac mounted the share in /Volume/Webdav. But all the permissions are only for the user who mounted the share. Now I would like to run an app on the Mac, whose permissions has not the users permission. How can I define a mounting mask (fe. like mask=777) to enable that all users can read/write the files on the mounted WebDav Share. The Server where the Folder is located is an WIN 10 PC with IIS WebDav enabled. Thanks for any helpfull advices.
Walter

Comment: could you please share which authentication you have enabled on iis for the WebDAV site and authoring rule? which permission is assigned to the WebDAV folder? is both the server is on the same domain? windows authentication will not work with mac os. you could try to use basic authentication.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal thanks, in the meantime I realized that the commercial WebDAV APP for Mac `ocsmount Pro` works fine with the permissions. I would be happy if it could be done  also in a terminal shell with a mask option maybe. But no luck.

Comment: you could try to use this command:  `chmod -R 777 /Your/folder/path/`

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I tried it of course, but as the folder is mounted it did not work.